# Incoming connections to Skype in 50656 and 45623 ports

Tags: ports, skype

I've seen many attemps connections from different and unknown IP's to my mac computers (two different Macs) to 45623 and 50656 ports.

Little Snitch says it's trying to connect to Skype but I can't find information about these ports in Skype's documentation.

May I have a malwared version? Any other strange skype behaviour around?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was the right stackexchange because it was a security related question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype uses randomized ports. You can also change this port in Skype’s settings.

Skype is also a peer-to-peer network, so incoming connections are normal. 
On Skype’s website, there’s [an article](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10983/what-are-p2p-communications) on P2P (both in general and in Skype).